# I am getting a bug in the code,can anyone help me in fixing the bug

Tags: python

```
max = 0
min = 0

while True:
  xx = raw_input('enter the value:')
  if xx == 'Done':
    break
  try:
     a = float(xx)
     if a>max:
       max=a
     if a<min:
       min=a
     continue
  except:

        else:
           print 'Invalid input'
           exit()

print 'Maximum is',max
print 'Minimum is',min
```

Comment: Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You have an `else` statement in your `except` block with no associated `if` statement.

Comment: NO even after removing the else statement I am getting an error and its is displaying as error with  if a>max and the error is unexpected intendation